# Javascript Number.toString(radix) behavior

Tags: javascript, numbers, radix

Why `(73).toString(36)` returns `21` and `(0.73).toString(36)` returns `0.qa2voha2volfpsnhmyhqia4i` and not 0.21?

Comment: Err, you cannot shift the decimal around an equivalent number of characters and assume it will work across bases. That does *not* work. `2` decimal is `10` binary, but `20` decimal isn't `100` in binary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because floats are stored as binary fractions (a number divided by a power of 2), and 73/100 cannot be expressed as a non-repeating fraction in binary. Thus internally, it's storing a value *close* to 0.73 but not exactly equal. That's why you get so many digits in the toString() method.

73/100 also can't be expressed as a non-repeating fraction in base 36. In general, for a fraction a/b you can only get a fixed number of digits after the decimal point in a given base x if you can reduce a/b to the form c/(x^n) for some integers c and n.

Answer (score 6):

```
73 = 2 x 36 + 1
0.73 = 26/36 + 10/(36 * 36) + ...
```

Like in hex we have `0, ..., 9, a, b, c, d, e, f` with `f` being the 16th *digit*, in 36-base system we have `0, 1, ..., 9, ..., q, ..., z` with `q` being the 26th *digit* and `a` the 10th `digit`.

The cause of this issue lies in that `0.21` in 36-base is `36` times smaller than `21` in 36-base and not `10` times.

Comment: Of all the answers and posts I have read - your explanation was the easiest to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Numbers of 36 base will have 36 digits: from 0 to z.

73 in base 10 = 21 in base 36, because `1 + 2 * 36 = 73`.

Float numbers are not calculated that way at all. `(0.5).toString(2)` is not `0.101`, but `0.1`. 0.73 calculated converted to any base will return a number that would be exactly 73% way from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

## number => Alphabet

```js
let childs = [];
for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
    childs.push(
        i.toString(36)
    );
}

// 26

childs;

// (26) ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
```